# How to get the "CC" email addresses in VBA from a specific email folder in Outlook?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

How do I retrieve CC email addresses from a mail in an Outlook folder using VBA?

I have this error

> Run-time error '91':
> Object variable or With block variable not set

```vb
Sub CC_EMAIL()
Dim lngCounter As Long
lngCounter = 2
Const PR_EMAIL = &H39FE001E
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = "CC Name"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value = "CC Email"
'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 3).Value = "Cc-Recipients"
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMsg = objOL.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
Set objSmail = CreateObject("Redemption.SafeMailItem")
objSmail.Item = objMsg
For Each recip In objSmail.Recipients
    If InStr(objSmail.CC, recip.Name) Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(lngCounter, 1).Value = recip.Name
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(lngCounter, 2).Value = recip.Fields(PR_EMAIL)
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(lngCounter, 3).Value = objSmail.CC
    lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What line is returning the error? That will give you a hint as to where the problem lies.  You should see a line highlighted when the code stops with the error message.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld it's ```Set objMsg = objOL.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem``` but I have no idea what's the problem with it

Comment: Perhaps if you explain how you are selecting the email item from which you want to extract the CC's, I can understand better what you are trying to do.  In the past, I've selected email items from a Folder object.

Comment: There is no object named objMsg when you have just opened Outlook. If the code was written in Outlook VBA instead you would open a mailitem before running the code. Search for examples where Outlook calls Excel.

Comment: If you start in Excel see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151811/reference-a-folder-by-name to specify a folder. After this you could loop through the items in the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, check that `objOL.ActiveInspector` is not null. It will exits only if there an email shown in a separate inspector.

Secondly, to test whether a recipient is CC, use the `Type` property. Change the line

```
If InStr(objSmail.CC, recip.Name) Then
```

to

```
If recip.Type = 2 Then '2 is olCC
```