# Write in active Outlook folder

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, office-automation

I would like Excel to write in the active folder of Outlook using VBA. But I am struggling to even define the path to the currently active folder.

Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
 Sub Test_folder_path()
     Dim myFolder As Object
     Set myFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
 End Sub
```

The error that I get is `Error 438: ("Object Doesn’t Support this Property or Method")`

If I try to define other types for `myfolder`, `Set myfolder` asks for an object.

I would be really happy about any advice, since I'm looking for a solution to this since hours!

I'm working with Office 2021.

Answer (score 1):

To work with MS Outlook from VBA-Excel you need to either late bind or early bind with it.

In your example, `Application` will refer to MS Excel and not to MS Outlook.

Here is an example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test_folder_path()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim myFolder As Object
    Set myFolder = OutApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    
    MsgBox myFolder.Name
End Sub
```

I recommend reading [Using early binding and late binding in Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/binding-type-available-to-automation-clients)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked like a charm!

Now everybody using the Macro just has to pay attention that the right folder is active in Outlook. ;-)

Is there also an option to address folders in public (company internally) section of Outlook by name/path? 
(In my case I have an "Info" folder with a subfolder "tasks" in it, which I would like to address.)

Comment: Why do you not let the use pick the folder?

Comment: Well I can of course! However if some users make the mistake of activating the macro when the wrong folder is selected, then the macro writes in the wrong folder. So I just thought it would be more fool-proof, if the macro already knows where to write without any user input. Because it will always be the same folder anyhow...  More a nice to have then a must though.

Comment: You can always post validate the name of the folder and the parent folder (`Info | Tasks`) and ask them to select again. I am not sure about `public (company internally)` folders. I do not have an option to test it and hence I am not suggesting anything.

Comment: To designate the Outlook folder from Excel. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151811/reference-a-folder-by-name