# Populate a website text area from HTML emails

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm using this VBA code to populate a website text area from HTML emails in outlook.

I would like to remove HYPERLINK `"website"website` and HYPERLINK `"mailto:email@email.com"email@email.com` from `mailitem.body` while retaining text.

How should I do it?

`ie.document.getElementById("message").Value = Replace(objItem.Body, vbCrLf & vbCrLf, vbCrLf)`

some examples:

www.google.com

comes out in the textarea as HYPERLINK "www.google.com"www.google.com
emails come out was HYPERLINK "mailto:dr_patso@email.com"dr_patso@email.com

Comment: regular expressions? It would be helpful, if you could post an example text you extracted (shortened of course, but with the full hyperlinks.

Comment: Hi Johanness, I added some examples.. but website and email would be the normal text you see. Im going nuts, objitem.body is supposed to present the body in clear text it doesn't at all, EVER.. but this is my last hurdle..

Comment: `mailitem.Body` is the text body which will have been created from the html body by removing formatting commands and converting links to text.  Try `mailitem.HtmlBody`.

Comment: As an alternative, look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11876549/973283. This question is nothing like yours but my answer includes a routine that creates an Excel workbook that contains the text and html bodies of all messages in the Inbox. Running that macro would be an easy way to see the bodies of a selection of emails and perhaps help you refine your question.

Answer (score 0):

use this,, start using "txt" instead of objitem.body for populating.

```
If objItem.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML Then
txt = objItem.Body
strt = InStr(txt, "HYPERLINK")
do until strt = 0
  nd = InStr(strt + 13, txt, """")
  txt = Left(txt, strt - 1) & Mid(txt, nd + 1)
  strt = InStr(txt, "HYPERLINK")
loop
End If

If objItem.BodyFormat = olFormatRichText Then
txt = objItem.Body
strt = InStr(txt, " HYPERLINK")
do until strt = 0
  nd = InStr(strt + 13, txt, """")
  txt = Left(txt, strt - 1) & Mid(txt, nd + 2)
  strt = InStr(txt, " HYPERLINK")
loop
End If
```

then populate text area with body..

If objItem.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML Then
  ie.document.getElementById("message").Value = Replace(txt, vbCrLf & vbCrLf, vbCrLf)
  End If
  If objItem.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain Then
  ie.document.getElementById("message").Value = objItem.Body
  End If
  If objItem.BodyFormat = olFormatRichText Then
  ie.document.getElementById("message").Value = txt
  End If