# Office 2010 VBA - pass SenderEmailAddress to Excel workbook and run Excel macro to send email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, outlook-2010, mail-sender

I've been asking people that are more familiar with VBA than I with not the kind of luck that I am hoping for.  Here's what I need:

- incoming email with "Stats1", "Stats2", "Stats3" (etc.) in the subject line
- rule is triggered, capture the sender's email address
- open workbook and pass the email address to the workbook (example: emaillog.xlsm)
- append to workbook (not overwrite)
- log the email address, time and date on "emaillog.xlsm"
- run an excel script (example emailsend.xlsm)
- send range of data from "emailsend.xlsm" to most recent entry on "emaillog.xlsm"
- save and close "emaillog.xlsm"

Here's what I have for the Excel part to send:

```
Public dTime As Date
Sub AutoSchedule1()
    dTime = Now() + TimeValue("01:00:00")
    Sheet("Sheet1").Range("u1").Value = "Email On, next send at " & Hour(dTime) & ":" & Minute(dTime)
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.OnTime dTime, "SendStatsTeam"
    If Hour(dTime) >= 18 Then
        Application.OnTime dTime, "SendStatsTeam", , False
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
Sub SendStatsTeam()
    Dim AWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim Sendrng As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Hournow As Long
    AutoSchedule1
    On Error GoTo StopMacro
    If Hour(Now()) > 12 Then
    Hournow = Hour(Now()) - 12
    Else
    Hournow = Hour(Now())
    End If
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set Sendrng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z26")

    Set AWorksheet = ActiveSheet

    With Sendrng

        ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
        With .Parent.MailEnvelope

            .Introduction = "Here are your stats"

            With .Item
                .To = SenderEmailAddress
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "Stats so far today" & Hour(Now()) & ":" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Minute(Now()), "00")
                .Send
            End With

        End With

        rng.Select
    End With

    AWorksheet.Select

StopMacro:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False

End Sub

Sub emailoff()
Application.OnTime dTime, "SendStatsTeam", , False
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("u1").Value = "Email Off"
End Sub
```

I realize that I have not done everything correctly here as I'm fairly new to VBA but I have tried everything that I can to figure out the Outlook part.

Any help would be appreciated - I don't mind doing the reading I'm just at a point that I can't figure out what/where to go for the next part.

If you choose to help, I would like to add the ability to send different ranges of different sheets based on the subject of the email.

Thanks

Comment: do you start you 8 points (dots) procedure from Outlook or Excel? how and where do you set connection of both application?

Comment: Started with Outlook with a rule.

Answer (score 0):

**Initial posting**

This is not an answer.  It is partly a request for clarification and partly a reference to an earlier answer which I believe will help you progress.

There is little difference  between a VBA macro written for Outlook and one written for Excel.  Is there a reason why you want to run an Excel macro from Outlook?  It would be easier to include the macro without Outlook.  For example something like this:

- New item event macro triggered by new email.
- Macro checks for subject.
- If subject is a keyword, open appropriate Excel workbook, store details of email, create reply from information in workbook and close workbook.
- Move processed emails to archive folder.

In response to earlier questions, I created a macro that demonstrates writing to Excel from Outlook.  That macro does not match your requirement but demonstrates lots of techniques that will be relevant.  Click https://stackoverflow.com/a/12146315/973283 to visit that answer.

I hope the above points are helpful.  Do come back with clarifications or further questions as necessary.

**Posting 2 after the requirement for clarified**

This next part of the answer is later than I hoped.  Partly because it has been a busy day and partly because I encountered a problem I had not expected.

From within Outlook select the Visual Basic Editor by:
 - selecting Tools then Macro then Visual Basic Editor or
 - clicking Alt+F11.

Down the left will be the Project Explorer which could be:

```
- Project1 (VbaProject.OTM)
  + Microsoft Outlook Objects
  + Forms
  + Modules
```

If you have no forms or modules, these entries will be missing.  Any entries that are present may already be expanded.  Expand `Microsoft Outlook Objects`, if not already expanded, by clicking the `+`.  The display will change to:

```
- Project1 (VbaProject.OTM)
  - Microsoft Outlook Objects
      ThisOutlookSession
  + Forms
  + Modules
```

Click `ThisOutlookSession`.  The top right area will become white (if it is not already white).  This is a code area, like a module, but is for special code.

Paste the code below into the `ThisOutlookSession` code area.

This code contains two macros.  The first macro, Application_Startup(), is automatically executed when Outlook is opened.  It specifies that the arrival of a new item in the Inbox is to trigger a call of macro `myNewItems_ItemAdd()`.  It also outputs "Welcome" to demonstrate that it has been called.  The second macro,  `myNewItems_ItemAdd()` identifies the type of the new item and outputs selected information to the Immediate Window.

These macros execute correctly but there is a problem I have not solved.  Outlook correctly, in my view, is unhappy about macros and macros that access emails in particular.  When you open Outlook it tells you there are macros (providing you have an adequate security level) and offers you the option of enabling or disabling those macros.  If a macro attempts to access an email, Outlook warns you and offers the option of permitting access for up to 10 minutes.

I have self-certified these macros which tells Outlook I trust them.  This suppresses the warning about macros being present but does not, as I expected, suppress the warning about a macro attempting to access emails.  I will investigate further for my own interest but having to be ready to give permission every 10 minutes defeats the objective of you having a new item event.

I suggest you play with these macros anyway because knowing this functionality exists may be helpful later.

I can think of three situations:

- If you work for a large company with an IT department, you probably cannot self-certify anyway because you need administrative privileges to do so.  You will need to seek the advice of the IT Department.
- If I cannot identify how to suppress the requirement to give permission every 10 minutes, perhaps someone else on Stack Overflow can.
- Once per hour, say, you could run a macro which would look for any request emails that had arrived since the last run.  If the macro found any, you would give permission for it to process them.  If this approach appeals, I definitely know how to implement such a macro.

.

```
 Option Explicit
 Public WithEvents MyNewItems As Outlook.Items
 Private Sub Application_Startup()

   ' This event procedure is called when Outlook is started

   Dim NS As NameSpace

   Set NS = CreateObject("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

   With NS
    Set MyNewItems = NS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
   End With

   MsgBox "Welcome"

 End Sub
 Private Sub myNewItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

   ' This event procedure is called whenever a new item is added to
   ' to the InBox.

   Dim NewMailItem As MailItem

   Debug.Print "------Item Received"

   On Error Resume Next
   ' This will give an error and fail to set NewMailItem if
   ' Item is not a MailItem.
   Set NewMailItem = Item
   On Error GoTo 0

   If Not NewMailItem Is Nothing Then
     ' This item is a mail item
     With NewMailItem
       Debug.Print "Subject " & .Subject
       Debug.Print "Sender Email [" & .SenderEmailAddress & "]"
     End With
   Else
     ' Probably a meeting request.
     Debug.Print "Not mail item " & Item.Subject
   End If

 End Sub
```

For my next posting, I will add an Outlook macro that opens a workbook and writes to it and reads from it.

In your question you say you want to send a range from the workbook to the author of the email. Do you know how to do this?  If not what sort of range would you send?  How would you want it to appear?  Converting a small range to Html is not difficult if that would give you the appearance you seek.

**Final posting**

Sorry but I am giving up on this question.  Nothing I have tried prevents Outlook from reporting that a macro is trying to send an email.  Everything else about this question is straightforward but this issue is a killer.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I went through your link and while it does give me some answers, it's still a bit confusing for me.  Your bullet points perfectly identify what I want to build - where can I find some sample code to put into what I've already built?

Comment: It is too late for me tonight.  I will post something tomorrow.