# Extract body text from Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I am working on a vba macro to extract the text contained in an email that is sent to me every day at a specified email address
I want to generate a vba macro that triggers when this arrives.
The text needs to be saved to a text file "c:\temp\email.txt"

I have collated various bits of code, but nothing really works.

Can anyone advise a simple vba method to do this?

Comment: Share with us the code that you tried and didn't work, so that we don't suggest to you something you've already tried.

Comment: To be honest, I have tried several bits of code offered on this site, but I cannot see where only mail from/to a specific email address can be included. I do not want it to work on every item that arrives. So really starting from scratch on this one ... thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may find my answer to [How to copy Outlook mail message into excel using VBA or Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12146315/973283) gives you a start.

That answer shows how to run down the Inbox extracting selected information from every email including sender, subject and text body. With this as a start you could write a macro that searches the Inbox for the email of interest and exports it to a text file.

What you really want is an event routine that is triggered when an item is added to the Inbox but that is more advanced so get a macro that searches Inbox working first.

Outlook has a robust security system so you will find when you run the search macro that you have to give it permission to access your emails.  You can self-certify your own macros but I have never managed the final step of suppressing the "A macro is accessing your emails" message. If you run the macro once a day, giving permission is not a problem but if you want to have an event routine you will have to confirm the permission every 10 minutes.

Visit the following sites for information or seek help elsewhere:

- Signing your own macros with SelfCert.exe: http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/selfcert.htm
- Manage Trusted Root Certificates: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754841.aspx

I can get the instructions in the first to work but not those in the second.

If you can crack the Manage Trusted Root Certificates problem, adding an event routine is not difficult.  Within Outlook's Visual Basic Editor, The project explorer will look something like this:

```
-  Project1(VbaProject.OTM)
   +  Microsoft Office Outlook Objects
   +  Forms
   +  Modules
```

Click the pluses as necessary to get:

```
-  Project1(VbaProject.OTM)
   -  Microsoft Office Outlook Objects
      *  ThisOutlookSession
   +  Forms
   +  Modules
```

Select `ThisOutlookSession`.  This is like a module but has extra privileges.  Copy the code below to `ThisOutlookSession` and you have the start of the event routine you seek.

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents MyNewItems As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_MAPILogonComplete()

  Dim NS As NameSpace

  Set NS = CreateObject("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

  With NS
    Set MyNewItems = NS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
  End With

End Sub
Private Sub myNewItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

  Dim text As String

  Debug.Print "--------------------"
  Debug.Print "Item added to Inbox"
  With Item
    Debug.Print "Subject: " & .Subject
    Debug.Print "Sender name: " & .SenderName
    Debug.Print "Sender address: " & .SenderEmailAddress
    text = Mid(.Body, 1, 100)
    text = Replace(text, vbLf, "{lf}")
    text = Replace(text, vbCr, "{cr}")
    text = Replace(text, vbTab, "{tb}")
    text = Replace(text, Chr$(160), "{nbsp}")
    Debug.Print "Start of body: " & text
  End With
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments - it is really gratifying to know people who spend time trying to help others. I shall try and work through your comments and see where I get !

Comment: Hi - when i try and run this it says: Invalid attribute in sub or function - highlights "WithEvents MyNewItems As Outlook.Items"

Comment: I have tried everything I can think of but I cannot duplicate your error. My only suggestion is that `WithEvents` is defined in a library which is referenced in my Outlook installation but not yours. I cannot test this suggestion because I cannot delete my references without deleting all my macros first. Within the Outlook VB Editor, click on Tools then References. I have the following ticked: `Visual Basic for Applications`, `Microsoft Outlook nn.n Object Library`, `Microsoft Office nn.n Object Library`, `Microsoft Forms nn.n Object Library`,   _continued in next comment_

Comment: `Microsoft Excel nn.n Object Library` and `OLE Atuomation`. The value of "nn.n" depends on the version of Office you are using. If any of these are unticked, particularly the first two, try ticking them. Unticked references are listed in alphabetic order so you will have to scroll down to find them.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I should perhaps add that no Outlook reference that I have checked mentions any difficulties with `WithEvents`.