# VBA Outlook 2010: Monitor new emails in public fodler

Tags: vba, outlook, monitoring, outlook-2010

whenever a new mail arrives in a public folder, I would like a MsgBox to pop up. I solved this for my own inbox using this code:

```
Private Sub Application_NewMail()

Dim oNS         As NameSpace
Dim oFolder     As MAPIFolder
Dim oNewMail    As MailItem

Set oNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set oNewMail = oFolder.Items.GetFirst

MsgBox oNewMail.subject    

End Sub
```

I also managed to access and retrieve the latest email from the public folder by replacing:

```
Set oFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
```

by

```
Set oFolder = oNS.Folders(2).Folders(2).Folders("XX").Folders("XX")
```

Howver, this obviously only works, when I manually evalute the code since the code is only executed when a new mail arrives in my inbox. I did some googling and found a potential solution to monitor a public folder:

```
Private WithEvents TestMail As Items

Public Sub Application_Startup()
    Set TestMail = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(2).Folders(2).Folders("XX").Folders("XX").Items
End Sub

Private Sub TestMail_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    MsgBox ("new mails arrived")
End Sub
```

Edit - The error when compiling: Unknown attribute in sub or function. I am using Outlook 2010 professional.

Comment: From the comment in Eugene's answer "I fixed the error by putting the WithEvents code snippet into a class module." Your source should have indicated all the code would go in the ThisOutlookSession module.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code:

```
Private WithEvents NewMail As Items

Public Sub Application_Startup()
   Set NewMail = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(2).Folders(2).Folders("XX").Folders("XX").Items
End Sub

Private Sub NewMail_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
   MsgBox ("new mails arrived")
End Sub
```

However, I'd recommend breaking the long chain of calls:

```
Set NewMail = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(2).Folders(2).Folders("XX").Folders("XX").Items
```

and declare each property or method call on  a separate line of code. Thus, you will find the exact ptoperty or method call which generates the error.

You may find the [How to get reference to Public Folder Store using Outlook Object Model for Outlook 2010?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brijs/archive/2010/07/30/how-to-get-reference-to-public-folder-store-using-outlook-object-model-for-outlook-2010.aspx) article helpful.

Comment: Hi, whats different in your code? I copied & pasted the code but same error. You might be right, splitting the code but the error already happens at the Private WithEvents... Might this be a wrong setting in outlook itself?? Hope that is right, but I have put the code in "ThisOutlookSession"

Comment: Just found this stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796071/extract-body-text-from-outlook I just checked my references and all are there besides that one: Microsoft Forms nn.n Object Library - However, i cannot find that one. Not sure whether that is causing the problem

Comment: I fixed the error by putting the WithEvents code snippet into a class module. However, the code still does not work.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Do you get and error messages?

Comment: just nothing happens. So if a new mail comes into the public or shared folder, the message box which should come up just doesnt. seems like the code is not executed

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint and see whether the event is fired or not.