# How to extract content from an E-Mail (Outlook) to an excel table?

Tags: vba, email, excel, outlook

I am trying to extract the content from an E-Mail in Outlook to an Excel table via VBA.

The E-Mail is for holiday management.
In the subject, there are always the keywords "**Accepted holiday - Mr. James**" Mr. James is the name of the employee, which holidays were accepted. So the keywords "**Accepted holiday**" is always the same, but the name always changes.
The E-Mail contains a long table, but there is only the end needed.
Maybe it's the best, if it is searching for some keywords.

> Datum von 18.12.2014
> Datum bis 18.12.2014
> Tage  1

Excel file contains:

- List item
- The lines **1** and **2** are empty.
- The line **3** contains the dates from the year.
- Line **4** contains Mo, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fr, Sat, Sun
- Line **5** is empty
- Line **A6**, **A7**, **A8**, .... contains the workers names
- And then in the lines **6**, **7**, **8**,... there should be "**X**" for the days, in which the worker has holidays.

```
Const xlUp As Long = -4162

Sub ExportToExcel(MyMail As MailItem)
    Dim strID As String, olNS As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strFileName As String

    '~~> Excel Variables
    Dim oXLApp As Object, oXLwb As Object, oXLws As Object
    Dim lRow As Long

    strID = MyMail.EntryID
    Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olMail = olNS.GetItemFromID(strID)

    '~~> Establish an EXCEL application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oXLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    '~~> If not found then create new instance
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    '~~> Show Excel
    oXLApp.Visible = True

    '~~> Open the relevant file
    Set oXLwb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Sample.xls")

    '~~> Set the relevant output sheet. Change as applicable
    Set oXLws = oXLwb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    lRow = oXLws.Range("A" & oXLApp.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    '~~> Write to outlook
    With oXLws
        '
        '~~> Code here to output data from email to Excel File
        '~~> For example
        '
        .Range("A" & lRow).Value = olMail.Subject
        .Range("B" & lRow).Value = olMail.SenderName
        '
    End With

    '~~> Close and Clean up Excel
    oXLwb.Close (True)
    oXLApp.Quit
    Set oXLws = Nothing
    Set oXLwb = Nothing
    Set oXLApp = Nothing

    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Please, post your code.

Comment: @segarcs I did, sorry :)

Comment: Sorry, I have only just noticed this question. This answer of mine might help. [How to copy Outlook mail message into excel using VBA or Macros](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12146315/973283)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to automate Excel from Outlook. The [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Visual Basic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/219151) article describes all the required steps.