# Open email in specific folder

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I'm having issues accessing emails in a specific folder within Outlook.

When I put the emails in the Inbox, the following line of code works.

```
Set OtlkApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.application")
Set ns = OtlkApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set fldr = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
```

However, when I try to access a folder called "tempfiles", it could not find the object when I tried opening it using this code.

```
Set fldr = ns.Folders("tempfiles")
```

Is the syntax correct? Am I missing something?

Comment: I know of no simple assignment statement that will allow you to access a randon folder.  You might have many folders with the same name; how will Outlook know which you want.  There are a pair of macros at the bottom of this answer of mine which will get any folder within the hierarchy.  [How to copy Outlook mail message into excel using VBA or Macros](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12146315/973283).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the level of tempfolders (same level or subfolder of Inbox) you extend the folders property:

```
'INBOX FOLDER
Set inboxfldr = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

'TEMPFILES SUBFOLDER
Set tempfilesfldr = inboxfldr.Folders("tempfiles")

'TEMPFILES FOLDER (SAME LEVEL AS DEFAULT FOLDERS -INBOX, CALENDAR, TASKS, ETC.)
Set tempfilesfldr = inboxfldr.Parent.Folders("tempfiles")
```