# Find "carriage return" in a mail.body

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have mails like this :

> Hello,
>
> Please note we did ... at  16h15
>
> Actions done:  Rebuilding etc
>
> sincerely
>
> Mr.

The actions change in every mail and what I want is to insert the action in my Excel. The problem is that I don't know how to get the "carriage return" (idk if this is the right name, this is what traduction gave me). 
What I find in internet is that `vbLfChr(10)` is the "carriage return".
What I tried is to find the beginning :

```
TechnicPosition= InStr(1, .Body, "Actions done: ")
TechnicAction= Mid(.Body, TechnicPosition, 14) ' first char from the action
```

But I can't get the last char (first "carriage return" from TechnicAction).
I tried many things like : `InStr(TechnicPosition, .Body, vbCrLf)`

My question : how to get a sentence that begin from a word to a "carriage return" (the first that comes after the beginning word) ?

Comment: It's just a line feed, use `vbLf` instead of `vbCrLf`

Comment: `vbLf` or `Chr(10)` = Line Feed, `vbCr` or `Chr(13)` = Carriage Return, `vbCrLf` = Carriage Return & Line Feed

Comment: I tried them all before I asked. They all return all the end of the mail body

Comment: Try the macro in this answer of mine: [How to copy Outlook mail message into excel using VBA or Macros](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12146315/973283).  It should give you all the detail you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `carriage return` in the email body is usually `vbNewline`

This is how I usually do it

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sBody As String
    Dim MyAr
    Dim i As Long

    '
    '~~> Rest of your code
    '

    sBody = oMail.Body

    '~~> For testing purpose
    'sBody = "Hello," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    'sBody = sBody & "Please note we did ... at 16h15" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    'sBody = sBody & "Actions done: Rebuilding etc" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    'sBody = sBody & "Sincerely"

    '~~> Split the email body on vbnewline and store it in array
    MyAr = Split(sBody, vbNewLine)

    '~~> Loop through array
    For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
        '~~> Check if the line has "Actions done:"
        If InStr(1, MyAr(i), "Actions done:") Then
            '~~> This would give you "Rebuilding etc"
            '~~> Split the line on "Actions done:"
            '~~> You will get an array. Ar(0) will have "Actions done:"
            '~~> And Ar(1) will have what you are looking for so we use
            '~~> Split()(1) directly to access that item
            MsgBox Split(MyAr(i), "Actions done:")(1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Edit**

[ANOTHER WAY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876549/how-to-copy-outlook-mail-message-into-excel-using-vba-or-macros/11877451#11877451)

Comment: I don't understand what you've done here, but it works perfectly. Thank you very much :D

Comment: I have added the explanation :) Still if you have a confusion, simply ask :)

Comment: I don't understand why there is a `(1)` at the end of the `Split`. PLus, is this important to set all the `set` to `nothing` at the end ?

Comment: You may have to refresh the page. I already explained what `Split()(1)` does :)

Comment: Thank you again, you have no idea how you helped me. It's quite frustrating not to find something that simple

Comment: While it is usually not necessary to use `Set obj = Nothing` in VBA but I always like to flush after I use the toilet ;)

Comment: I now understand your whole answer but i'd never think about this solution. Thank you again (and i'll flush ;))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TechnicPosition = InStr(1, .Body, "Actions done: ")
TechnicEndPosition = InStr(TechnicPosition, .Body, Chr(10))
TechnicAction = Mid(.Body, TechnicPosition + 14, TechnicEndPosition - TechnicPosition - 14)
```

Comment: It still doesn't find the "carriage return"

Comment: It there a way to see all char in a mail (to see how the carriage return is coded)

Comment: Add this to your code: `For i = 1 To Len(.Body): Debug.Print "[" & i & "]: " & Mid(.Body, i, 1) & " (Asc: " & Asc(Mid(.Body, i, 1)) & ")": Next i`. It will print all the characters in the Immediate window.

Comment: It gives me `[152]: 
 (Asc: 13)
[153]: 
 (Asc: 10)
[154]: 
 (Asc: 13)
[155]: 
 (Asc: 10)`

Comment: Ok, so try the same code as above but change this: `Chr(10)` to `Chr(13)`

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the body to see what the character is:

```
For i = 1 To Len(.Body)
    If Not Mid(.Body, i, 1) Like "[A-Za-z0-9,'?!"".:]" Then
        Debug.Print Asc(Mid(.Body, i, 1))
    End If
Next
```

Once you've found the `Asc()` value, split the body on it and return the second index:

```
TechnicAction = Split(.Body, Asc(10))(1) '// Or whatever Asc() is required
```

Comment: I've updated the pattern, I made a typo but I've also added some extra characters.