# How to script Outlok text editor using Visual Basic?

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to perform some text replacements that are just too complicated for Automatic replacement feature of Microsoft outlook. Microsoft has rather extensive [documentation on Microsoft Outlook VBA scripting](https://github.com/OfficeDev/VBA-content/tree/master/Outlook-VBA) hosted on GitHub.

I started by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> which opened Visual Basic Editor. This is what I see in the project explorer:

[image: image description]

Please note that I am not VBA programmer, so what I did afterwards probably looks stupid. I figured out that `OutlookOutlook` namespace represents all Outlook classes, so I just picked one of the classes that sounds like a text field:

```
Dim WithEvents textField As Outlook.OlkTextBox
```

And I created a dummy event that should fire before change in text field:

```
Private Sub textField_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "Nope!"
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Of course, when start outlook and edit message, the script doesn't get executed. So I suppose that for starter, I need to get a refference to actual text editor. How do I do that?

My question basically is, how to get this code execute when I try to edit any outlook message:

```
    MsgBox "Nope!"
    Cancel = True
```

Comment: I suggest you look for documentation/questions on `ActiveExplorer` which returns a collection of the currently selected mail items. This would allow you to select the mail items you wish to edit before starting a macro that processed each in turn.  To me this sounds closer to the functionality you seek than your current code.

Comment: Do you know the structure of the text bodies and/or html bodies of the mail items you wish to edit? If not my answer to this question may help: [How to copy Outlook mail message into excel using VBA or Macros](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12146315/973283). This macro creates a workbook containing selected properties of mail items including the contents of their text bodies and html bodies.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [write](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868664.aspx) event.

```
Private WithEvents myItem As MailItem 

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set myItem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem 
End Sub

Private Sub myItem_Write(Cancel As Boolean) 
    MsgBox "Nope!"
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```