# VBA keeps trying to open Worksheet, but don't want it to

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I've got a VBA that writes e-mails from outlook to excel. However, I want this excel sheet to remain open. Currently i've got the sheet to stay open (and just save after an e-mail goes into it), but each time i receive a new e-mail into my work book, it asks me to  reopen the workbook as the VBA is telling it to open the workbook.

Here is the code:

```
Sub ExportToExcel(MyMail As MailItem)

    Dim strID As String, olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strFileName As String

    '~~> Excel Variables
    Dim oXLApp As Object, oXLwb As Object, oXLws As Object
    Dim lRow As Long, fRow As Long

    strID = MyMail.EntryID
    Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olMail = olNS.GetItemFromID(strID)

    '~~> Establish an EXCEL application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oXLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    '~~> If not found then create new instance
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    '~~> Show Excel
    oXLApp.Visible = True

    '~~> Open the relevant file
    Set oXLwb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open("\\C:\Rachael\VBAs\Control Panels.xlsm")

    '~~> Set the relevant output sheet. Change as applicable
    Set oXLws = oXLwb.Sheets("Ash Data")

    '~~> Write to outlook
    With oXLws
        '~~> Code here to output data from email to Excel File
        '~~> For example

        '* insert into last row (old alternative)
        '* you can remove this and the declare of lRow (at the top) if you don't need the old last row insert anymore.
        'lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'next new row
        '.Range("A" & lRow).Value = olMail.Body 'write into last row

        '* insert into first row
        fRow = 1 'first row
        .Rows(fRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        .Range("A" & fRow).Value = olMail.Body 'write into first row
    End With

    '~~> Close and Clean up Excel
    oXLwb.Save
    Set oXLws = Nothing
    Set oXLwb = Nothing
    Set oXLApp = Nothing

    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing

End Sub
```

I'm not sure where I am going wrong with this code, but perhaps someone knows a solution to this?

Comment: Next time you use a code from one of our users, at least mention it and send us the link to that post. Anyway, "it asks me to reopen the workbook" because you told it to : `Set oXLwb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open("\\C:\Rachael\VBAs\Control Panels.xlsm")`

Comment: Hi, I think this is the original that I used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876549/how-to-copy-outlook-mail-message-into-excel-using-vba-or-macros but how do i change that line so rather than opening it, it will just look for it, as this sheet will always remain open? I tried removing the .open but it gives me an error?

Comment: see my answer below, see it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, you can use another method to check if your Workbook is already open, without error traps. You can loop through  the open Excel workbooks, and compare them to the `FullName` you are looking for (`"\\C:\Rachael\VBAs\Control Panels.xlsm"`).

If there is a match >> then `Set oXLwb` to that workbook.

If there isn't a match >> then `Open` the relevant workbook.

**Code**

```
Dim oXLApp As Object, oXLwb As Object, oXLws As Object
Dim XLopenWB As Object
Dim Flag As Boolean

Flag = False
For Each XLopenWB In oXLApp.Workbooks
    If XLopenWB.FullName Like "\\C:\Rachael\VBAs\Control Panels.xlsm" Then
        Flag = True
        Set oXLwb = XLopenWB
        Exit For
    End If
Next XLopenWB

If Not Flag Then
    ' open the relevant workbook
    Set oXLwb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open("\\C:\Rachael\VBAs\Control Panels.xlsm")
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Shai, I'm pretty bad at code stuff I've just been introduced to it this week so sorry if this sounds really dumb but, does that code go above 'open the relevant workbook' ? or does this go into an entirely new vba? Thanks!

Comment: @Rachael you should delete the lines `'~~> Open the relevant file` , and `Set oXLwb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open("\\C:\Rachael\VBAs\Control Panels.xlsm")` , and instead paste my code

Comment: Thanks Shai this is great, can't thank you both enough!!

Comment: @Rachael you can only have 1 answer marked as "ANSWER" , so choose wisely ;) either way is cool. You can Upvote the other answer

Comment: I know! Gutted, I just tried to click you both but was unable to :( im going eenie-meenie-miney-mo it!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Shai in the comments, the issue is that your macro is opening the `Workbook` every time it is run regardless of whether the `Workbook` is already open. Siddharth Rout's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373082/detect-whether-excel-workbook-is-already-open) question provides a `IsWorkBookOpen` function which will check whether the workbook is open or not, you can then open the workbook if it returns `False`:

```
Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)

Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

On Error Resume Next
ff = FreeFile()
Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
Close ff
ErrNo = Err
On Error GoTo 0

Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
End Select

End Function
```

Then you can change your code to the following:

```
'~~> Open the relevant file
If IsWorkBookOpen("\\C:\Rachael\VBAs\Control Panels.xlsm") Then
    Set oXLwb = oXLApp.Workbooks("Control Panels.xlsm")
Else
    Set oXLwb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open("\\C:\Rachael\VBAs\Control Panels.xlsm")
End If
```

Comment: Hi Jordan, thanks for that. I have changed my code under 'open the relevant file' however i'm not sure where i am to put the top code you provided 'Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)'

Comment: You can just put that before or after the Sub (e.g. before the line `Sub ExportToExcel(MyMail As MailItem)` or after `End Sub`)

Comment: Thank you Jordan this has worked perfectly for me! Cannot thank u both enough!