# Outlook VBA code to export parts of body to Excel not working

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I've used a variety of resources from stackoverflow  and a few other places to get some code in VBA. This is the third iteration I've tried and still haven't gotten it to work. The first iteration was written mostly from scratch, but didn't work. The second iteration was based on [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697493/update-excel-sheet-based-on-outlook-mail). I had the code in the ThisOutlookSession Outlook Object to run at startup. The current iteration is based on [this stackoveflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876549/how-to-copy-outlook-mail-message-into-excel-using-vba-or-macros) and is in it's own Module. It's run using a rule in Outlook.

The part that gets the data from the email body has seemed to work fine in the previous iterations of the code. But the part that writes to Excel doesn't seem to be working, and hasn't worked in any of the previous iterations and I don't know why.

I have a rule set in Outlook to run the macro on emails with a specific subject line. These emails are structured in a specific way that makes it easy to get the data. The rule also sets these emails to read, which it does, so I can see the rule works.

I have an Excel sheet in My Documents with the first row being dedicated to labeling the columns. Though I've tried this with an empty Excel sheet as well and it still didn't work.

The email body looks something like this:

---

ID: 608

FirstName:  test

MiddleInitial:  t

LastName:   testet

BirthDate:  01/01/1900

Gender: Male

StreetAddress:

City:

State:

Zip:

Ethnicity:

dtAdded:    01/19/2016

Area:   Hair Loss

Area:   Skin Cancer

---

There could be anywhere from 0 to 12 Areas, each simply labeled as Area. Below is some of the code I have. I've trimmed some of the repetitive parts so it isn't as long (still kind of long, sorry):

```
Option Explicit

Const xlUp As Long = -4162

Sub ExportToExcel(MyMail As MailItem)
    Dim strID As String, olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strFileName As String

    '~~> Outlook Variables
    Dim idNum As String
    Dim firstName As String
    Dim middleInitial As String
    Dim lastName As String
    Dim birthDate As String
    Dim gender As String
    Dim streetAddress As String
    Dim city As String
    Dim state As String
    Dim zipcode As String
    Dim ethnicity As String
    Dim dateAdded As String
    Dim area1 As String
    Dim area2 As String
    Dim area11 As String
    Dim area12 As String
    Dim areaOther As String
    Dim areas As String


'~~> Process Outlook Stuff
idNum = ParseTextLinePair(olMail.Body, "ID:")
firstName = ParseTextLinePair(olMail.Body, "FirstName:")
middleInitial = ParseTextLinePair(olMail.Body, "MiddleInitial:")
lastName = ParseTextLinePair(olMail.Body, "LastName:")
birthDate = ParseTextLinePair(olMail.Body, "BirthDate:")
gender = ParseTextLinePair(olMail.Body, "Gender:")
streetAddress = ParseTextLinePair(olMail.Body, "StreetAddress:")
city = ParseTextLinePair(olMail.Body, "City:")
state = ParseTextLinePair(olMail.Body, "State:")
zipcode = ParseTextLinePair(olMail.Body, "Zipcode:")
ethnicity = ParseTextLinePair(olMail.Body, "Ethnicity:")

Dim intLocLabel As Integer
Dim intLocCRLF As Integer
Dim intLenLabel As Integer

'area1
intLocLabel = InStr(olMail.Body, "Area:")
intLenLabel = Len("Area:")
    If intLocLabel > 0 Then
        'vbCrLf = new line
        intLocCRLF = InStr(intLocLabel, olMail.Body, vbCrLf)
        If intLocCRLF > 0 Then
            intLocLabel = intLocLabel + intLenLabel
            area1 = Mid(olMail.Body, _
                        intLocLabel, _
                        intLocCRLF - intLocLabel)
        Else
                       ' this was Mid(..
            area1 = Mid(olMail.Body, intLocLabel + intLenLabel)
        End If
    End If

    'area2:
    If intLocCRLF > 0 Then

    intLocLabel = InStr(intLocCRLF, olMail.Body, "Area:")
    If intLocLabel > 0 Then
        intLocCRLF = InStr(intLocLabel, olMail.Body, vbCrLf)
        If intLocCRLF > 0 Then
            intLocLabel = intLocLabel + intLenLabel
            area2 = Mid(olMail.Body, _
                    intLocLabel, _
                    intLocCRLF - intLocLabel)
        Else
                                ' this was Mid(..
            area2 = Mid(olMail.Body, intLocLabel + intLenLabel)
        End If
    End If

    End If

    'area11:
    If intLocCRLF > 0 Then

    intLocLabel = InStr(intLocCRLF, olMail.Body, "Area:")
    If intLocLabel > 0 Then
        intLocCRLF = InStr(intLocLabel, olMail.Body, vbCrLf)
        If intLocCRLF > 0 Then
            intLocLabel = intLocLabel + intLenLabel
            area11 = Mid(olMail.Body, _
                    intLocLabel, _
                    intLocCRLF - intLocLabel)
        Else
                                ' this was Mid(..
            area11 = Mid(olMail.Body, intLocLabel + intLenLabel)
        End If
    End If

    End If

    'area12
    If intLocCRLF > 0 Then

    intLocLabel = InStr(intLocCRLF, olMail.Body, "Area:")
    If intLocLabel > 0 Then
        intLocCRLF = InStr(intLocLabel, olMail.Body, vbCrLf)
        If intLocCRLF > 0 Then
            intLocLabel = intLocLabel + intLenLabel
            area12 = Mid(olMail.Body, _
                    intLocLabel, _
                    intLocCRLF - intLocLabel)
        Else
                                ' this was Mid(..
            area12 = Mid(olMail.Body, intLocLabel + intLenLabel)
        End If
    End If

    End If

    'areaOther is easy because it has the Other Skin Problems label
    areaOther = ParseTextLinePair(olMail.Body, "Other Skin Problems,")


If InStr(area1, "Other Skin Problems,") = 0 Then
    areas = areas & area1
End If
If InStr(area2, "Other Skin Problems,") = 0 Then
    areas = areas & area2
End If
If InStr(area3, "Other Skin Problems,") = 0 Then
    areas = areas & area3
End If
If InStr(area4, "Other Skin Problems,") = 0 Then
    areas = areas & area4
End If
If InStr(area5, "Other Skin Problems,") = 0 Then
    areas = areas & area5
End If
If InStr(area6, "Other Skin Problems,") = 0 Then
    areas = areas & area6
End If
If InStr(area7, "Other Skin Problems,") = 0 Then
    areas = areas & area7
End If
If InStr(area8, "Other Skin Problems,") = 0 Then
    areas = areas & area8
End If
If InStr(area9, "Other Skin Problems,") = 0 Then
    areas = areas & area9
End If
If InStr(area10, "Other Skin Problems,") = 0 Then
    areas = areas & area10
End If
If InStr(area11, "Other Skin Problems,") = 0 Then
    areas = areas & area11
End If
If InStr(area12, "Other Skin Problems,") = 0 Then
    areas = areas & area12
End If

'~~> Excel Variables
Dim oXLApp As Object, oXLwb As Object, oXLws As Object
Dim lRow As Long

strID = MyMail.EntryID
Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olMail = olNS.GetItemFromID(strID)

'~~> Establish an EXCEL application object
On Error Resume Next
Set oXLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

'~~> If not found then create new instance
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

'~~> Show Excel
oXLApp.Visible = True

'~~> Open the relevant file
Set oXLwb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\$$MYUSER$$\Documents\$$MYFILENAME$$.xlsx")

'~~> Set the relevant output sheet. Change as applicable
Set oXLws = oXLwb.Sheets("Sheet1")

lRow = oXLws.Range("A" & oXLApp.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'~~> Write to outlook
With oXLws
    '
    '
    .Range("A" & lRow).Value = idNum
    .Range("B" & lRow).Value = dateAdded
    .Range("O" & lRow).Value = firstName
    .Range("P" & lRow).Value = middleInitial
    .Range("Q" & lRow).Value = lastName
    .Range("R" & lRow).Value = birthDate
    .Range("S" & lRow).Value = gender
    .Range("T" & lRow).Value = streetAddress
    .Range("U" & lRow).Value = city
    .Range("V" & lRow).Value = state
    .Range("W" & lRow).Value = zipcode
    .Range("AE" & lRow).Value = ethnicity

        With .Range("C" & lRow)
            If InStr(areas, "Acne") > 0 Then
                .Value = "Yes"
            End If
        End With

        With .Range("H" & lRow)
            If InStr(areas, "Hair Loss") > 0 Then
                .Value = "Yes"
            End If
        End With

        With .Range("J" & lRow)
            If InStr(areas, "Skin Cancer") > 0 Then
                .Value = "Yes"
            End If
        End With

        With .Range("L" & lRow)
            If InStr(areas, "Wrinkles") > 0 Then
                .Value = "Yes"
            End If
        End With   


    End With

    Debug.Print idNum
    Debug.Print firstName

    '~~> Close and Clean up Excel
    oXLwb.Close (True)
    oXLApp.Quit
    Set oXLws = Nothing
    Set oXLwb = Nothing
    Set oXLApp = Nothing

    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
End Sub
Function ParseTextLinePair(strSource As String, strLabel As String)
    'This function extracts the data from any label-data pair that appears
    'in a block of text, where all the label-data pairs are on separate
    'lines. A typical application would be parsing the text sent as email
    'by a form on a web site, where the incoming message has multiple lines
    'each with a different Label: Data pair

    Dim intLocLabel As Integer
    Dim intLocCRLF As Integer
    Dim intLenLabel As Integer
    Dim strText As String

    ' locate the label in the source text
    '   InStr returns 0 if srtLabel is not found in strSource
    '   InStr returns the position of the first occurance of strLabel in strSource
    intLocLabel = InStr(strSource, strLabel)
    intLenLabel = Len(strLabel)
    If intLocLabel > 0 Then
        intLocCRLF = InStr(intLocLabel, strSource, vbCrLf)
        If intLocCRLF > 0 Then
            intLocLabel = intLocLabel + intLenLabel
            strText = Mid(strSource, _
                            intLocLabel, _
                            intLocCRLF - intLocLabel)
        Else
            strText = Mid(strSource, intLocLabel + intLenLabel)
        End If
    End If
    ' the Trim function can be useful to remove non-printing and
    '     leading or ending spaces from text
    ParseTextLinePair = Trim(strText)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Sub ExportToExcel(oMail As mailItem)
```

or

```
Set olMail = myMail
```