# Insert String into Body of received email

Tags: vba, outlook

I wish to take the body of the selected received email (in folder view or as a selected email) and add an action stub to the beginning e.g.…

```
.Body = StubString & 'Body
```

I am uncertain how to use `ActiveInspector` and `mailitem` etc.

I have looked through the list of answered questions but I can't find one that will help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Warnings:

- Few of the emails I receive have a text body (property .Body) that I would wish to view or amend for someone else to view. Most have an html body (property .HTMLBody).  If there is a text body, it is a crude simplification of the html body.
- The email packages I use only show the text body if there is no html body. Amending the text body would have no effect on the display unless you delete the html body.

Between them, I believe the two answers and the macro below will give all the background you need to create your macro.

This answer of mine is a tutorial taking the reader through the Outlook Object model with the example macros you find most helpful. You should probably skip this now and come back later because I believe the second answer is closer to your requirement.  [Update excel sheet based on outlook mail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8699250/973283)

This second answer demonstrates how to create an Excel worksheet and copy selected properties of a mail item to it so the user can see what a mail item looks like to a VBA program. As written, the macro outputs details of every mail item in the Inbox. Comments within it, show how to limit the macro's output to selected emails so you can examine the content of the mail items you wish to amend.  [How to copy Outlook mail message into excel using VBA or Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12146315/973283)

Both the above answers examine all mail items in a selected folder. If you select a few mail items then run the macro below, you will get selected properties of those mail items.

```
Public Sub DemoExplorer()

  Dim Exp As Outlook.Explorer
  Dim ItemCrnt As MailItem
  Dim NumSelected As Long

  Set Exp = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer

  NumSelected = Exp.Selection.Count

  If NumSelected = 0 Then
    Debug.Print "No emails selected"
  Else
    For Each ItemCrnt In Exp.Selection
      With ItemCrnt
        Debug.Print "--------------------------"
        Debug.Print "From: " & .SenderName
        Debug.Print "Subject: " & .Subject
        Debug.Print "Received: " & Format(.ReceivedTime, "dMMMyy h:mm:ss")
        'Debug.Print "Text " & Replace(Replace(Replace(.Body, vbLf, "{lf}"), vbCr, "{cr}"), vbTab, "{tb}")
        'Debug.Print "Html " & Replace(Replace(Replace(.HTMLBody, vbLf, "{lf}"), vbCr, "{cr}"), vbTab, "{tb}")
      End With
    Next
  End If

End Sub
```